# Adding a date()/timestamp to each MongoDB item upon creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, io, timestamp

this is my second question today regarding Node.js. It's late, and I'd like some help to quickly integrate this function before I can go to bed.

I have a small Q&A app in which I can read and write data from/to MongoDB on my views pages.

However, I'd like to make a timestamp or date() register itself with each instance of items being written to MongoDB.

On the views, for now, only the author, title and body of text must be visible. But when I query Mongo, I'd like to have a seperate property that lists the date and time created. (Date alone suffices)

I have defined a property "date" : Date, in my Schema. I assumed it would automatically add this, but only title, author and body are added. I think it is because they are defined as vals in the routes for discussions but I'm note sure.

These are my code files:

discussions.js -- /routes

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Discussion = require('../models/discussions');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){

    // alle db records uitlussen, op render alldiscussions
    var db = req.db;
    Discussion.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('all_discussions', {
            "all_discussions" : docs
        });
        console.log(docs);
    });
});

router.get('/create', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('add_discussion', {title: 'Diskussr'});

});

router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {

    //set DB
    var db = req.db;

    //form vals
    var author = req.body.name;
    var title = req.body.title;
    var body = req.body.body;

    //set collection
    var collection = db.get('discussions');

    //insert
    collection.insert({
        "author" : author,
        "title" : title,
        "body" : body
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("Database submit error");
        }
        else {
            res.location("all_discussions");
            res.redirect("all_discussions");
        }
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

add_discussion.jade -- /views

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Start a discussion
  p Start a discussion here on #{title} and help eachother out.
  p Voeg hier uw vraag in:
  form(action="/submit" method="post" name="submit_discussion")
  input(id="name", placeholder="Your name" name="name")
  br
  br
  input(id="title", placeholder="Brief summary of your problem." name="title")
  br
  br
  input(id="body", placeholder="Explain your problem." name="body")
  br
  br
  button(type="sumbit" id="submit" value="submit") Submit
  br
```

discussions.js -- /models

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//schema discussions
var DiscussionSchema = new Schema({
    author: String,
    title: String,
    body: String,
    category: String,
    created: Date
},
{ collection : 'discussions' });

// model
var Discussion = mongoose.model('Discussion', DiscussionSchema, 'discussions');

// test functie: aanmaken vraag on load
// var firstDiscussion = new Discussion({author: "Testuser 1", title: "Testvraag via models"});
// console.log(firstDiscussion);

// //vraag saven
//  firstDiscussion.save(function (err, firstDiscussion){
//      if (err) return console.error(err);
//  });





module.exports = Discussion;
```

Comment: The objectId of the inserted document should already have a creation timestamp built in, you don't need a field for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a default value for the `created` field:

```
//schema discussions
var DiscussionSchema = new Schema({
    author: String,
    title: String,
    body: String,
    category: String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
},
{ collection : 'discussions' });
```

Or, since you are using ObjectId as primary key, you can extract the timestamp  using `getTimestamp()` as suggested by @adeneo:

```
Discussion.find({}, function(e,docs){
    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log("created: " + doc._id.getTimestamp());
    });
});
```